# Does the vacuum energy of the infinite spacetime have a gravitational pull on the matter in the observable universe?

Tags: energy, gravity, vacuum

I understand that there is a basic energy to the vacuum, the observable universe and any matter beyond it is surrounded by and infinite continuous spacetime, does the energy of that spacetime exert any sort of gravitational pull on the matter in the universe, I know it doesn't account for the expansion of the universe but is this happening in any minute capacity.

Comment: Which direction would it pull matter?

Comment: I would assume outward but I want to keep the question open to gravity broadly whatever effect it might have.

Comment: Consider an atom being pulled. There is an infinity of “outward directions” from it. Which one of them is it going to move in?

Comment: If all the matter in the universe is in an orb (or any shape) expanding outwards and you are close to one edge of all the finite matter made by the big bang the pull from the part of the empty vacuum you are closest to is the strongest and therefor the direction you will be pulled in

Comment: It’s not in an orb.

Comment: Theres a finite amount of matter surrounded by infinite empty space some aprts of the matter must be closer to the esges

Comment: Observations indicate that.our universe doesn’t work that way. What you are envisioning bears no relationship to mainstream cosmology.